# Show that f is discontinuous in 1.

Tags: calculus, continuity

Use $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition to show that $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{|x-1|}$ is discontinues in 1.

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to solve this. Can someone give me a good explanation?

Comment: do you know $\varepsilon-\delta$ defenition?

Comment: do you have to do it using $\epsilon-\delta$ proof? because there are easier ways

Comment: Yes I know, but not how to show is for discontinuity.

Comment: You are supposed to show it with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$

Comment: @MathiasBakkejord Your question doesn't make sense, unless you tell us what $f(1)$ is.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Well, that's all the information you've got. "Use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition to show that f is not continues i point 1."

Comment: @MathiasBakkejord If $1$ does not belong to the domain of $f$, then $f$ is discontinuous at $1$ *by definition*. The $\epsilon-\delta$ part of the definition is relevant only for the points of the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{\epsilon_+\to 0}f(x+ \epsilon)|_{x=1}=\frac{x+\epsilon-1}{|x+\epsilon-1|}=\frac{\epsilon}{|\epsilon|}=+ 1$$

$$\lim_{\epsilon_-\to 0}f(x- \epsilon)|_{x=1}=\frac{x-\epsilon-1}{|x-\epsilon-1|}=\frac{-\epsilon}{|\epsilon|}= -1$$

$f(x+ \epsilon) \neq f(x- \epsilon)$ , so it is discontinues at  $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The function $f(x)$ is not even defined in $x=1$. Normally you have to say something like $f(x)=1$ for $x=1$ and $f(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{|x-1|}$ for $x\neq 1$. Look at $x-1>0$ hence $f(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{x-1}=1$ and $x-1<0$ which implies $f(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{-(x-1)}=-1$.